# Files installed by GoToAssist

Tags: installation

I had to install the GoToAssist product for Verizon Tech Support to look at my PC.  I was carefull to watch what he was doing and to shut if off and exit once he was finished.

I would like to know what files (if any) I should delete, process/services to kill, or registry entries to remove to ensure that none of the files are left on my mahcine.

Comment: Worked with a Verizon FIOS tech on Jan 24, 2012 and he requested that I browse to www.verizon.net/showme. That put up a screen offering GoToAssist. It downloaded and installed quickly, and was quite helpful. The next day I wanted to remove it, but I see no trace on this WinXP machine's Add/Remove Programs window. Found a folder C:\Program Files\Citrix\GoToAssist\514. It was empty, parent folders had no files. Browsed over to http://www.gotoassist.com/remote_support/ hoping to find a FAQ about this but nothing, nada, zip. Maybe the current version really does delete itself!?

Answer (score 1):

I use GoToAssist pretty heavily on the Support side; I believe it leaves an entry in Add/Remove Programs.  Other than a Quick Start icon in the Notification Area, I don't think it keeps any services running on the client side.

If you want to do additional verification:

- Registry entries and executables will usually have `g2ax_` somewhere
- It's a Citrix product, so if you don't have anything else Citrix-based on your system, Citrix* is a good target.

Actually, that should cover you.

As a side note, you have to ask G2A to initiate a connection; having it installed doesn't turn your machine into part of Verizon's botnet...